# Solr eDismax Lucene query issue

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, edismax

I'm working with a system that uses the eDismax query parser, which I believe has support for Lucene syntax, but I'm having an issue getting queries to work without Solr searching for "AND" and "OR" as literal keys used in the search criteria.

I can currently get the Dismax syntax to work with +'s to collect an intersection of results:

```
http://...:8983/solr/collection/requesthandler?debugQuery=on&defType=edismax&fq=documents:"docgroup"&q=cat+dog+pizza&start=0&rows=50&sort=doc_date+asc
```

I'm looking Lucene syntax to work with OR's:

```
http://...:8983/solr/collection/requesthandler?debugQuery=on&defType=edismax&fq=documents:"docgroup"&q=(cat+OR+dog)+AND+(pizza+OR+Hawaii)&start=0&rows=50&sort=doc_date+asc
```

The debug line is returning something like:

```
"rawquerystring":"(cat OR fish OR dog) AND (pizza OR Hawaii OR 2001)"
"querystring":"(cat OR fish OR dog) AND (pizza OR Hawaii OR 2001)"
"parsedquery":"(+(DisjunctionMaxQuery((docsection1:cat | docsection2: cat | ...... docsection1:or | docsection2:or ....
```

where "or" and "and" are included as keys in the search

Is this a configuration issue?  Am I building the query wrong?  The 6.6 Solr reference guide references this syntax:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?defType=edismax&q=ipod+OR+video
```